# _CrtIsValidHeapPointer is consuming too much cpu on Windows 10 1809, Why?

Tags: performance, visual-c++

I have encountered a weried problem about _CrtIsValidHeapPointer in a debug version of a dll, which compiled using msvc2017 compiler. When the debug version (with debug version of vc runtime) is loaded and running, the performance is terrible. I confirmed that most of the cpu is consumed by the calling to _CrtIsValidHeapPointer, which is called from operator delete or free(C function). Because it it pretty common to allocate and free object on the heap, the _CrtIsValidHeapPointer is called often and it leads to very laggy interaction, and somethings may cause the program to be unresponsive.

I have tried many different methods, here is what I found:

- Linking with static lib version or dll version of the VC CRT makes no difference.
- Using WinSDK 8.1 or 10.0 makes no difference
- When running the dll under Win10 1803, it works fine. Under Win10 1809, laggy and unresponsive.

Now I have no idea why the Win10 version lead to a different behavior and how.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Performance is supposed to be terrible, especially so for this function.  Debug your program only with small data sets so perf is never an issue.  Once you build the Release version then this kind of UB checking is no longer done and you can verify that your code meets the project's performance requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this check process in DEBUG version? It seams that it's not easy to separate the dll easily from the whole system and make standalone test cases for it. Now it makes debuggin for the dll completely impossible.